# change link background in jQuery datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, database

i have a script. jQuery datepicker with url's on database.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                beforeShowDay: daysToMark,
                onSelect: function(date,evt){
                    if (evt.currentMonth < 10){
                        evt.currentMonth = "0"+evt.currentMonth;
                        }
                    if (evt.currentDay < 10){
                        evt.currentDay = "0"+evt.currentDay;
                        }
                        daysToMark(evt.currentYear+"-"+evt.currentMonth+"-"+evt.currentDay);
                        date.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a')
                        .css('background-color', '#000000');
                        }
                });
        });

        <? 
        $dateArray = array();
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT *
                            FROM module_news
                            "); 
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                    array_push($dateArray,$row["tarigi"]);
                    }
        ?>
        var js_array = new Array();
        js_array = <?=json_encode($dateArray);?>;
        var dates = js_array;
        function daysToMark(evt) {
            if($.inArray(evt, js_array) != -1 )
            {

                window.open("index.php?action=news_archive&date="+evt+"&lang=<?=$lang?>", "_self");
            }
        return [true, "", ""];
        }
       </script>
```

I have database date links in array, and i want to highlight links, so when i write news at **2011-07-08** on my calendar it 'll be linked but not highlighted, how can i change background color of linked dates?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `daysToMark` method you return `return [true, "", ""];` as required by the `beforeShowDay` event.

The second position in that array hold a class that will be applied to the data. So if you add a class there `return [true, "linked", ""];` and in you css code set a rule of

```
.linked .ui-state-default{
  background-color:red;
  background-image:none; /*this in case the them you use uses background images*/
}
```

it should do what you want..

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/S79fa/

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
date.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a')
                        .css('background-color', '#000000');
```

with below code

```
var atag = date.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a');
atag.queue(function() {
   atag.css("background-color", "black");
});
```

this may be helpful

Thanks.